# Узнать количество атрибутов без использования this.attrs

Tags: javascript, framework, компоненты, ember.js

В одном из компонентов `ember.js` в идеале необходимо получить количество переданных атрибутов в Handlebars-шаблоне. Необходимо это для оптимизации, банально чтобы не выполнялся большой кусок кода.

Можно получить количество атрибутов через `Object.keys(this.attrs).length`. Это работает корректно, но компилятор выдает предупреждение:

`Do not use this.attrs  ember/no-attrs-in-components`

Понятно что `this.attrs` лучше не использовать. От того вопрос: Есть ли в `ember.js` альтернатива этому. Хотя бы какой-то флаг, позволяющий понять, указаны ли для данного компонента какие либо атрибуты.

Comment: готовое решение http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sesavo/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @inDevX `this._keywords` не определен

Comment: Ну предупреждение, а не ошибка же. Добавить исключение для компилятора, написать комментарий в месте использования и успокоиться

Comment: @alexeyTen В проекте стараемся не использовать решения на которые ругается компилятор. К тому же если в следующих версиях что-то изменится, не хотелось бы перебирать лишний раз весь код.

Answer (score 0):

Решение на основе предложенного [InDevX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/330342/indevx). Функция получает флаг наличия атрибутов. Проверено на Ember 3.х

```
hasAttrs() {
    let source = this;

    let exceptions = ["helperName", "templateData", "container", "elementId", 
                  "currentState", "classNames", "classNameBindings", "controller",
                  "toString", "buffer", "element","renderer",
                  "toast","parentView","layout","attrs"];

    for (let key in source) {

      if(key.charAt(0) === "_") continue;
      if (source.hasOwnProperty(key) && exceptions.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
},
```